# wget rename with original name

Tags: bash, ubuntu, wget

I am using the bash script to run something like below

```
for i in {1..50}; 
do  
    wget --content-disposition `http://example.com/getfile.php?id={$i}`
done
```

then I can get the files

```
abc.mp3
abc.jpg
abc.png
...
```

but I want to extend the id to the files like

```
1-abc.mp3
2-abc.jpg
3-abc.png
...
```

Can I use the `wget -o` rename the file to `{$i}-{$orignalName.orignalExtention}`

Answer (score 0):

First you should use a `HEAD` HTTP call to retrieve the `originalName`, for instance with:

- `-S --spider --content-disposition` options with `wget`
- `-I -L` options with `cURL`

For instance:

```
originalFileName=$( wget --content-disposition -S --spider "http://example.com/getfile.php?id={$i}" |& grep "Content-Disposition" |sed -e 's/^.*filename=//' )
```

Then simply use the -O option, and build your local file name with the just got `originalName` and the `i` you already owner.

With your script, it would give:

```
for i in {1..50}; 
do  
    originalFileName=$( wget --content-disposition -S --spider "http://example.com/getfile.php?id={$i}" |& grep "Content-Disposition" |sed -e 's/^.*filename=//' )
    wget `http://example.com/getfile.php?id={$i}` -O "$i-$originalFileName"
done
```

Answer (score -1):

`wget` doesn't support template/pattern in the `-O` (capital letter O, BTW) option. So you can do some trick like putting the file to a temporary directory first then rename it using shell. Something like:

```
for i in {1..50}; 
do  
    mkdir $i && cd $i && \
    wget --content-disposition `http://example.com/getfile.php?id={$i}` && \
    for fn in *; do mv "$fn" "../$i-$fn" && cd .. && rmdir $i; done
done
```

Note: untested.

Comment: Your `cd ..` and `rmdir` instructions should be outside the `for` instruction. Does this version manage file name with space characters?

Comment: Yes, they should. But I think they still work if put inside the `for` instruction. Yes, the double quotes in `mv` should handle the spaces.

Comment: Why did you use a `for` instruction if you intend to have only one file? (If they are several, it won't work with `cd ..` and `rmdir` instructions inside the `for` one).

Comment: Basically the `for` is used to capture the filename only. Because I glob in a newly created directory, there should be only one file which is the one downloaded by wget. Theoretically this could still fail if wget downloads into a dot file (e.g. `.foo.mp3`) as the wildcard * will also return empty.